# Calling a custom monad in haskell using the bind

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, console, monads, ghci

I am currently 'getting my feet wet with monads' (http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#getting-our-feet-wet-with-maybe) and still struggling with part of this concept. I understand the maybe monad mentioned there and can see how to call it, as mentioned here:

```
ghci> return "WHAT" :: Maybe String  
Just "WHAT"  
ghci> Just 9 >>= \x -> return (x*10)  
Just 90  
ghci> Nothing >>= \x -> return (x*10)  
Nothing
```

How do I however call my own monad instance rather than the maybe one if I declare my own instance with its own type, like so:

```
newtype CustomM a = CustomM {runCustomM:: a -> String}


instance Monad CustomM where
  return a = CustomM (\a -> mempty)
  m >>= f = CustomM (\a -> mempty)


instance Functor CustomM where 
  fmap = liftM 
instance Applicative CustomM where 
  pure = return; (<*>) = ap
```

using the `return` will just call the `Maybe Monad` I suspect. And what about the `>>=` it would require me to give it a certain type.

NB. I have only made the bind the same way as the return, because I still struggle with understanding what it is supposed to return, and how I can give it a monad `m` and call the function f on it's value `a`, when I don't specify the packed type more thoroughly in the left side. But I shall make another post about that.

Comment: Not all types can be made into lawful/meaningful monads. Or even functors. `a -> String` surely is not one of them. `String -> a` instead is, it is called (up to some isomorphisms) the "reader monad". `(String, a)` would also be ok (the "writer monad"). It is not an easy task to see if something is or can not be a monad, unfortunately.

Comment: @chi I think the monad definition here is lawful, though not very useful. It's isomorphic to `Proxy`, isn't it? The function being stored is always `mempty`, so you might as well not store it, at which point we have a zero-field type, just like `Proxy`.

Comment: @amalloy `fmap id = id` is broken, I think. Also, `m >>= return = m` is broken for a non-empty-returning `m`.

Comment: @chi Oh, sure, because the constructor is exported. I was imagining for some reason that the module controlled the constructor, but that's a silly assumption to make because how else are clients going to interact with this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a value of your `CustomM` type just like you did with `Maybe`, using `return`:

```
cm = return "WHAT" :: CustomM String
```

You can also run it, after a fashion:

```
Prelude Control.Monad> runCustomM cm "foo"
""
```

Clearly, though, since you've hard-coded it to return `mempty`, it returns the `mempty` value for `String`, which is `""`.

All that said, though, `a -> String` is [contravariant](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2021/09/02/contravariant-functors) in `a`, so it can't be a useful `Functor` instance. And since it can't be a useful `Functor` instance, it also can't be a useful `Monad` instance.

While you can define a degenerate implementation as in the OP, you're not going to have much success making `CustomM` do anything for real.

Try, instead, swapping the types like e.g. `String -> a`.

Comment: How do I actually access the Prelude Control.Monad> prompt , from ghci?

Comment: @Piskator you can `import Control.Monad` in GHCi.

Comment: I am note sure how to do that. When I write `import Control.Monad CustomM return "what"` in the console I get a parse error. And when I just write `return "what"` after writing  `import Control.Monad` I can see that it doesn't change the console into Prelude mode as seen in your example above, nor does it give a specific string `mempty` output or any other output I specify in the monad.

Comment: @Piskator Is [the GHCi documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html) of any help?

Comment: Not really, I try to do the following: 
`ghci> import System.IO
ghci> import System.IO as IO
ghci>`
as they suggest, but as you can shee it doesn't change the ghci to the System.IO !? It could be something that is wrong with the way my GHCI is installed perhaps.

Comment: @Piskator I don't have enough information to enable me to tell what's wrong, and these comments aren't the best channel for troubleshooting. You may want to consider asking a new question.

Comment: Ok, I shall try that htank you Mark