# how to change to prelude console in haskell for execution of monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, console, haskell-prelude

Hi I am trying to run a custom monad by using prelude as suggested here:[Calling a custom monad in haskell using the bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727177/calling-a-custom-monad-in-haskell-using-the-bind/73727764?noredirect=1#comment130318342_73727764) , by using `Prelude Control.Monad> runCustomM cm "foo"`

However when I try to do the `import Control.Monad` nothing happens an the prompt type doesn't change. Likewise nothing happens when I use the `System.IO` as suggested here:
[https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html)

How can I execute the prelude correctly s.t. I can execute my own Monads?

I tried

```
Loaded package environment from C:\Users\tqx98\AppData\Roaming\ghc\x86_64-mingw32-9.0.1\environments\default
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help

ghci> import Control.Monad
ghci> import System.IO 
ghci>
```

The above is more or less all that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I try to do the `import Control.Monad` nothing happens an the prompt type doesn't change.

This appears to be the expected behaviour in your version of GHCi, see [the documentation of v9.0.1](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/9.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#controlling-what-is-in-scope-with-import) (contrasting with [that of v8.4.2](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/8.4.2/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#controlling-what-is-in-scope-with-import) which you linked). In my experience, the long prompt was quite annoying when importing a lot of modules, so I'd consider it an improvement.

It just be working just fine to call the functions from the imported modules.

Comment: ahh... but how do I then execute a customized Monad, if the Control.Monad is already activiated. Do you know how I execute my custom monad, such as I requested in the linked post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73727177/calling-a-custom-monad-in-haskell-using-the-bind/73727764?noredirect=1#comment130318342_73727764 ?

Comment: You don't actually need to import `Control.Monad` for that, if you did define the `newtype CustomM a = CustomM {runCustomM:: a -> String}` in your ghci session (or `:load` the definition from a file) the `runCustomM` function already is in scope.

Comment: You might want to extend your question with the full transcript of the ghci session you ran and the error you got